# Fireshot for Firefox on Ubuntu (Linux)

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, browser-addons

I used Firefox for windows with the great Firefox extension called Fireshot, I then switched from Windows to Ubuntu and somehow Fireshot isn't available for Firefox for Linux. Are there any alternatives that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching through the Add-on site gave a few results that you may be interested in. Unfortunately, none seem to have quite as much functionality as Fireshot. Check out:

- [ScreenGrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146)
- [Talon Screen Capture and Edit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11587)

Comment: Talon has been removed

Comment: Screen grab is not compatible with most recent versions

Answer (score 1):

Awesome Screenshot works for both [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce?hl=en) and [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/awesome-screenshot-capture-/).

There is also 'Quick Markup' which is more stable, up to date with latest versions and got better features/interface. My faves are ability to crop/draw/put labels/ export jpeg. available for both FF and chrome here it is: [Quick Markup plugins](http://quick-markup.com/en/start)

Comment: Thank you, your timing could not be better. I was looking for another extension for screengrabs since I moved from Firefox to Chrome, will try it

Answer (score 1):

"awesome screenshot" works well as a FF extension and supports annotations.

There are others alternatives here as well : http://alternativeto.net/software/fireshot/?platform=linux

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Chrome, I've been using [Aviary](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ncgcgghbabbopfcpgcjpfffdgnbadegf) and I'm more than satisfied. They've got a bunch of other tools for advanced image editing too.